# Show $T$ is a sufficient statistic using definition of sufficiency

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability, parameter-estimation

Suppose I have two independent variables $X_i \sim Gamma(i\theta, 1)$ for $i=1,2$.

Show that $T= X_1 + X_2$ is a sufficient statistic using the definition of sufficient statistics (not the factorization criteria).

I am using the definition from Casella & Berger:

- If $p(\mathbf{x}|\theta)$ is the joing pdf or pmt of $\mathbf{X}$ and
  $q(t|\theta)$ is the pdf or pm of $T(\mathbf{X})$, then
  $T(\mathbf{X})$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ if, for every
  $\mathbf{x}$ in the sample space, the ration
  $\frac{p(\mathbf{x}|\theta)}{q(T(\mathbf{X}|\theta))}$ is a constant function
  of $\theta$.

Now clearly, $T \sim Gamma(3\theta, 1)$

Thus

\begin{align*}
f(X_1, X_2|T)= & \frac{f_{X_1}(X_1=x_1)f_{X_2}(X_2 = x_2)}{f_{T}(T=t)}\\
               & \\
             =  & \frac{\left ( \frac{\exp(-x_1 -x_2) x_1 ^{\theta-1}x_2^{2\theta-1}}{\Gamma(\theta)\Gamma(2\theta)}\right )}{\left ( \frac{\exp(-x_1 -x_2) (x_1+x_2 )^{3\theta-1}}{\Gamma(3\theta)}\right )}\\
    & \\
             = & \frac{\Gamma(3\theta)x_1 ^{\theta-1}x_2^{2\theta-1}}{\Gamma(\theta)\Gamma(2\theta)(x_1 + x_2)^{3\theta - 1} }
\end{align*}

Now this still looks dependent on $\theta$ to me.  Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Comment: What is the density of $\text{Gamma}(i\theta,1)$?

Comment: It is a gamma distribution with the first parameter being $\theta$ times a constant, in this case the constants are 1 and 2.  The second parameter is just 1.  Gamma generally has two types of parameterizations, in this case since the second parameter is 1, both types are equivalent.  Did that answer your question?

Comment: Gamma distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

Comment: If pdf of $X_i$ is $f_{X_i}(x)=\frac1{\Gamma(i\theta)}e^{-x}x^{i\theta-1}\mathbf1_{x>0}$ as you seem to have taken, then $X_1+X_2$ is not sufficient for $\theta$. "Did that answer your question?"- No, since you did not answer my question.

Comment: This is the standard formula for a gamma distribution.  I am legitimately not trying rude.  The formulas provided in the link match up to the pdf you provided.  Was there another version of the Gamma pdf you knew of? Genuinely curious.